# Request.session.get(String) returns Option[String] How do I use this?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, session-variables

I want to use a session value in pattern matching but since my request.get("profileType") returns Option[String] I cannot use it in pattern matching like I have in my code.
Here's my code snippet.

```
def editorProfile = Action { implicit request =>
request.session.get("profileType").toString() match {
  case "editor" => {
      request.session.get("userEmail").map {
        userEmail => Ok(html.profile.editorProfile("my profile"))
      }.getOrElse {
        Unauthorized(html.error("Not logged in"))
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
[MatchError: Some(editor) (of class java.lang.String)]
```

My question is. How do I use this Some(editor) from session.get in my pattern matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try to use a for comprehension because it might scale easier when you add more checks of a similar type.

```
val email = for {
  profileType <- request.session.get("profileType") if profileType == "editor"
  userEmail <- request.session.get("userEmail")
} yield userEmail

// email is of type Option[String] now, so we do the matching accordingly

email match {
  case m: Some => Ok(html.profile.editorProfile("my profile"))
  case None => Unauthorized(html.error("Not logged in or not an editor."))
}
```

You can of course write all that in an even more concise way but as a beginner, it does not hurt being more explicit.

**Addition:**

If you want to use the mail address later on, you could change it to:

```
email match {
  case Some(address) => Ok(html.profile.editorProfileWithEmail("my profile", address))
  case None => Unauthorized(html.error("Not logged in or not an editor."))
}
```

Comment: I could go search on google for answers but since you guys give such educational answers I rather ask here. When you use that for comprehension (which I'm not so familiar with, not sure what it does in the.. uhm.. loop? ;) Also, what does "yield userEmail" do? And also in the pattern matchin, when you write "case m:" what is this "m"? Don't know if I should ask all these questions in a comment. But let me know if I'm using commentfield wrong! :)

Comment: You mean in the `yield` part? In this case it is not really important as you don’t care about the actual mail address or the profile type later on. I just use the `yield userEmail` part to flag whether the `for` comprehension returned successfully. It does not actually loop in this case (well, it’s a loop with either zero or one element).

Comment: `m` is just a dummy variable which gets set when email is a Some. One could also use a `_` in this case as we never refer to it anyway but I thought this might be even more confusing. One might also extract the mail address from the Some by saying `case Some(address) => OK("Your Mail address is: " + address)` but yeah, there’s quite a few possibilities here. You’ll learn.

Comment: I actually need the email adress for later use. Would you edit something in your example in that case? Ok, I wont lay to much thoughts about yield atm then.

Comment: Big thanks for your good answers, and you're just right, I'll learn eventually! :)

Answer (score 2):

You call `toString` on `Option[String]` and get `"Some(editor)"`. Instead you must match on this:

```
request.session.get("profileType") match {
  case Some("editor") => { /* your code */}
  case _ => /* something else */ 
}
```

Note that I added default case `_ =>`.  Without it you can get `MatchError` if `session` didn't contains "profileType" attribute or attribute has another value.

Comment: You should also appropriately handle the case where it's not possible to get this with a `case None => ....`